# image cropping with codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, image-manipulation, gd

I am working with jcrop and codeigniter to allow users to crop images that they upload, I want to the image t crop to a size of 90x60 but what ever I try nothing seems to work, my current code looks like this,

**CONTROLLER**

```
function save_crop() {
        $this->load->library('image_lib');

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        //$config['library_path'] = '/usr/X11R6/bin/';
        $config['source_image'] = './media/images/uploads/company_uploads/' . $this->input->post('image_name');
        //$config['new_image'] = './media/images/uploads/company_uploads/cropped' . $this->input->post('image_name').'_'.time();
        //die($config['source_image']);
        $config['x_axis'] = $this->input->post('x');
        $config['y_axis'] = $this->input->post('y');
        $config['width'] = $this->input->post('w');
        $config['height'] = $this->input->post('h');
        $config['maintain_ration'] = TRUE;
        $config['dynamic_output'] = TRUE;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->image_lib->crop()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        } else {
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#jcrop_target').Jcrop({
        onChange: showPreview,
        onSelect: showCoords,
        aspectRatio: 1,
        addClass: 'custom',
        maxSize: [90,60]
    });

    function showPreview(coords)
    {
        var rx = 100 / coords.w;
        var ry = 100 / coords.h;

        $('#preview').css({
            width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
            height: Math.round(ry * 370) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
        });
    };

    function showCoords(c)
    {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#x2').val(c.x2);
        $('#y2').val(c.y2);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<?php if(isset($upload_data)) :?>
            <?php if($upload_data['image_width'] > 90 || $upload_data['image_height'] > 60) : ?>
            <p>Your image is a little large</p>
            <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>employer/save_crop" method="post">
            <div id="uploaded_image">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>media/images/uploads/company_uploads/<?php echo $upload_data['file_name'];?>" id="jcrop_target"/>
            </div>
                <div id="uploaded_preview">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>media/images/uploads/company_uploads/<?php echo $upload_data['file_name'];?>" id="preview"/>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="x" id="x" />
                <input type="hidden" name="y" id="y" />
                <input type="hidden" name="x2" id="x2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="y2" id="y2" />
                <input type="text" name="w" id="w" />
                <input type="text" name="h" id="h" />
                <input type="hidden" name="image_name" value="<?php echo $upload_data['file_name'];?>"/>
                <input type="submit" name="crop_image" value="Crop" />
            </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
```

You must put `maintain_ratio` instead of `maintain_ration`.

Answer (score 0):

If you posted the error message(s) that Codeigniter was throwing, it would allow us to be a lot more helpful.

Are you utilizing Codeigniter's 'Form helper' for validation? If 'maxSize' is set correctly in jCrop, you shouldn't be having any problems...

Errors please :)